# list created with javascript is not displaying list data from html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to log numbers from an HTML element without predefining a list. 
below is what I am currently using to attempt this but for some reason it is not adding the output to the created list element. note that the output is random. any help is appreciated.

```
function Log(c){
var c = document.getElementById('out').innerHTML;
var node=document.createElement("LI");
node.setAttribute("class" , f);
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node);
node.setAttribute("value" , c);
var f = y=y++;++y
var y = 0
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
node.setAttribute("value" , c);
```

to:

```
node.innerHTML = c;
```

The `value` attribute is only used for user input elements (`<input>`, `<option>`, etc.).